# Ajax Protection?

Tags: php, ajax

My ajax requests point to a URL which is linked to a controller then model that inputs the data in to a database.

My question is, what is to stop other people making an ajax call to that URL with data and entering it in my database.

How can I protect against this?

Comment: pass some hidden fields just like wordpress nonce...http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces

Comment: May be of use: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 4):

You cannot prevent people from faking AJAX calls. To put it another way, there is no way your script receiving the AJAX call can determine if the call is legit.

You have to implement some kind of high-level logic (hashes, passwords...) if you want to make sure the call is legit.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have built an API which you are calling from the client. Are you using REST or SOAP? Since most mobile application today work the REST API way, you could try the API Key approach described [here](https://www.stormpath.com/blog/top-six-reasons-use-api-keys-and-how).

If you don't have a client that can have the logic, then I would like to go with [Synchronizer Token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly separates users of your page from "other people"? Are they inputting data in the wrong format? Are they inputting too often? You should protect against these things specifically rather than try to control where the URL is being accessed from. For instance, if there are only 5 specific inputs that the ajax function sends, just design your controller to accept only those (or a number from 1 to 5) and pass the appropriate data to the model, and ignore all other calls.